# Typescript can you declare language features? eg; `!variable` as `no variable`

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to declare Typescript language features within the app's source code?

I would like to implement a really small feature to help the clarity of skimming code.

**Classic Null Test**

```js
if (!userDetails) {
   // handle null
}
```

**New Null Test**

```js
if (no userDetails) {
   // handle null
}
```

Just a tiny bit nicer in my opinion... Any help pointing me in the right direction in accomplishing this would be great, thanks!

**edit**: handle null as in handle when an object has not been set, I'm aware that this will also handle `false`, `''`, `undefined` etc.

Comment: `in my opinion` - well, that's the thing about opinions, everyone has one - if you truly wanted to handle null only, why not `if (userDetails !== null)` because `(!userDetails)` is true if `userDetails` is `false`, `""`, `0`, `NaN`, or `undefined` not just when it is `null`

Comment: And if the next version of TS or any ES feature introduces this syntax or syntax making this ambiguous, you have built yourself a nice foot gun.

Comment: Also, you can achieve something visually similar by creating a function that does this check (in whichever version you need it).

Comment: You might get https://www.sweetjs.org to work with typescript ...

Comment: Cheers for the criticism, yes that's much more rock solid

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this with template literal function

```js
function no(value){
  return arguments[1] ? true : false
}

let userDetails = null

if(no`${userDetails}`){
  console.log('not null')
} else {
  console.log('null')
}

if(no`${4}`){
  console.log('not null')
}
```

Comment: This is clever, I like it. But for a simple null check I'd argue this looks less idiomatic than, well, `!== null`. That's a problem in OP's question already, though...

Comment: Why not just `const no = v => !v` ?!

Comment: @JonasWilms yes you can, but you need to change it a bit. `const no = (v,...arg) => arg[1] ? true : false` because the Tag function signature is `(str, arg1,arg2...)`, which  eventually is same what i have already written

Comment: But why use a template literal at all? because you can? that makes little sense, `no(stuff)` is far more readable, and its idiomatic.

Comment: @JonasWilms `if(!stuff)` is even more readable mate. but what i considered op is asking something `keyword value to test`. i tried to achieve as close to that

Comment: But that's not really what you achieved here.

Comment: @JonasWilms well this is the closet i can think of. and writing a complete new keyword is just beyond scope and even i don't have that much knowledge too. and writing a complete new keyword have it's own complications

Answer (score 0):

> `no userDetails`

No. Syntax additions like this are not supported.

## More

Technically you can add them using language plugins, but its hard work and a bit obscure.

Answer (score 0):

No. I'm afraid that if you absolutely want to do that you you have fork TypeScript and create you language.

Bear in mind that the semantics of TypeScript are extremely well though of to make sure it does not collide with JavaScript syntax. For this particular exemple you posed, I can't think of a collision but there still might be.

Comment: It would make `no` a keyword, which could at least break existing code.

Comment: Yes I understand. When I said "make sure you will not collide with JavaScript" I meant that, depending on the changes you would make, you could convert otherwise valid JavaScript into whatever else